# How to add in localStorage different counter values in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localhost

I am creating a burger constructor. Below is the list of ingredients.I want the counter values to be saved when switching to another tab (through react-router).

```
return (
  <div className="ingredients">
    <div className="ingr-card">
        <div className="image-ingr">
          <img src={image} alt="cotlet" /> 
        </div>
        <div className="name-ingr">
          <p>{name}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="counter">
          <button disabled={!count} onClick={minus}>-</button>
          <p>{count}</p>
          <button disabled={count>=3} onClick={plus}>+</button>
        </div>
  </div>
  </div>);
```

**Render elements**

```
ingredients = [
{id: 1, name: 'Cutlet', image: './image/cutlet.png', imageHuge: './image/cutletHuge.png', gram: 350, price: 5.85, kcal: 280},
{id: 2,name: 'Mayo',   image: './image/mayo.png', imageHuge: './image/mayoHuge.png', gram: 30, price: 2.15, kcal: 40},
{id: 3,name: 'Onion',  image: './image/onion.png', imageHuge: './image/onionHuge.png', gram: 12, price: 1.55, kcal: 4},
{id: 4,name: 'Tomato', image: './image/tomato.png', imageHuge: './image/tomatoHuge.png', gram: 48, price: 4.25, kcal: 4},
{id: 5,name: 'Cucumber', image: './image/cucumber.png', imageHuge: './image/cucumberHuge.png', gram: 7, price: 3.55, kcal: 2},
{id: 6,name: 'Cheese', image: './image/cheese.png', imageHuge: './image/cheeseHuge.png', gram: 40, price: 5.15, kcal: 40},
{id: 7,name: 'Salad',  image: './image/salad.png', imageHuge: './image/saladHuge.png', gram: 6, price: 3.25, kcal: 3}
```

];

```
function ShowIngredients() {
return (
    <div className='show-ingredients'>
        {ingredients.map((obj, index)=>(
        <Ingredients name={obj.name} image={obj.image} key={obj.id} onPlus={obj}/>   
        ))}
    </div>
```

);
}

**I created a counter value for each ingredient**

```
  let burgerSetting = {"Cutlet":0, "Mayo":0, "Onion":0, "Tomato":0, "Cucumber":0, "Cheese":0, "Salad":0};
```

**Now I am adding to localStorage
But the values ​​of the counter of ALL ingredients change. Where is my mistake?**

```
 const getFromStorage = () => { 
const storage = window.localStorage.getItem('burgerSetting[name]');
return storage !== null ? parseInt(storage) : 0;
};
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(getFromStorage);
useEffect(
    () => window.localStorage.setItem('burgerSetting[name]', count),
    [count]
);
```

**Click on counter**

```
  const plus = () => {
setCount(count => count + 1);
const minus = () => {
setCount(count => count - 1);
```

[Image of ingredients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmj6l.png)

Comment: Please share a complete code example. See [mcve]. What are `minus` and `plus` doing? Do you have buttons for each ingredient? State for each? It looks like you are using a single `count` state.

Comment: `'burgerSetting[name]'` is a string not a variable causing the key to be non-unique. Try removing the quotes -> `burgerSetting[name]`

Comment: Sorry, the comments are a terrible place for code, can you edit your post to include a complete & comprehensive [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese i updated the question added more code and image

Comment: I mean, one complete cohesive code example. These partial snippets aren't helpful when we need to see the entire picture how they relate. I could try to piece them together to create something that is runnable, but I'd just be guessing.

Comment: @DrewReese how will i do it?maybe send github link?

Comment: Maybe copy/paste into your post here the `Ingredients` component code, the `ingredients` declaration or example array value, etc... A link to the repo would be helpful as an additional resource.

Comment: @DrewReese added ingredients array. This is all related code to the component with a counter. And here is the link to my repository https://github.com/YuliiaK1/Make-your-burger

Answer (score 0):

You must use JSON.stringify while setting item:

as it converts anything (except DOM elements) to String

and JSON.parse while getting item:

as it converts a String to its data type (e.g. "1" to Number 1)

For e.g.:

```
window.localStorage.setItem( "key", JSON.stringify(burgerSetting) );
let bs = window.localStorage.getItem( "key", JSON.parse(burgerSetting) );
window.console.log( bs["name"] );
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around 'burgerSetting[name]' on both places (getItem as well as setItem) becoz
`'burgerSetting['cutlet']'` gives `'burgerSetting['cutlet']'` and not `0`.

```
 const getFromStorage = () => { 
const storage = window.localStorage.getItem(burgerSetting[name]); // line changed
return storage !== null ? parseInt(storage) : 0;
};
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(getFromStorage);
useEffect(
    () => window.localStorage.setItem(burgerSetting[name], count), // line changed
    [count]
);
```

Comment: Then the code throws an error. Perhaps this is due to the fact that I have one state for all the ingredients? And I rendered all the ingredients through map ?